Is "cancellative semigroup" better English than "cancellation semigroup"?
From Wikipedia:

In mathematics, a cancellative semigroup (also called a cancellation semigroup) is a semigroup having the cancellation property

I understand that it is a technical term and that maybe different rules apply to technical terms, but if it was a standard expression in everyday English, is there a reason, from the perspective of grammar or English usage, for preferring "cancellative semigroup" to "cancellation semigroup"
Here, "semigroup" is a noun and "cancellative" is an adjective that seems to only appear in mathematics
From what I have seen, it is always "cancellative X" and never "cancellation X", where X is "semigroup" or some other noun

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

In reality, there is no concept of "better English" outside of actual usage. And it's obvious from this chart that despite being initially favoured for a couple of decades after it first started to appear, cancellation semigroup has been almost completely eclipsed by cancellative semigroup today.

Just as you can't fight City Hall, there's no point in arguing the syntactic or semantic merits of some particular phrasing, if the majority of your fellow Anglophones have already shown a clear preference for an alternative after your preferred version has been and gone.
English is what the majority of people say and write, not what a few people think (more accurately here, thought)..

EDIT: OP asked for a reason, which I originally thought couldn't meaningfully be answered. But prompted by @Peter's comment, I find that the far more common collocation commutative group, which was around much earlier, completely dwarfs the occasional commutation group. So the obvious "reason" for choosing cancellative semigroup is that it reflects an existing and familiar (to mathematicians! :) usage.

perhaps I could have phrased my question more accurately: I didn't see any difference between "cancellative semigroup" and "cancellation semigroup", and I wanted to know if there are syntactic or semantic reasons for choosing one over the other

I haven't bothered to read anything at all about the definition, but it looks like something relevant to mathematicians, who obviously aren't usually particularly knowledgeable about English grammar and morphology. So there's no justification for supposing the reason most mathematicians have obviously settled on cancellative here has anything to do with principles that might be meaningful to grammarians. In short, the reason they made the choice they did is probably either unknowable, or plain meaningless.

...arguably my revised answer "explaining" the usage by reference to previously-established  commutative group simply pushes the problem further back. I don't know why they chose that rather than commutation group.

I don't agree in the least with 'no concept of "better English" outside of actual usage'; usage is being changed every day with the aim of bettering the language, and  misnomers in a language are constantly the cause of discussion that people must find in the end very unproductive. I do agree with 'who obviously aren't [too often] particularly knowledgeable about English grammar and morphology'.

@LPH: Linguists constantly struggle with grammarians in this area, but obviously natural languages continually change over time, and the only "enduring" principle of "correct English" is indeed what people say (and to a far lesser extent, what some people write). I have a degree in English, but my opinion of "correct usage" cuts no ice with people who "prefer" something different. And any linguist will tell you that to a first approximation, natural languages don't "improve" over time - they just change.

@FumbleFingers 'And any linguist will tell you that to a first approximation, natural languages don't "improve" over time - they just change.' is a true revelation that cements my uncertain perceptions suddenly  into  an apparently more solid understanding.

@LPH: I was well into my 20s when it dawned on me that evolution doesn't lead to "objective improvement" over time - just continual adaptation to a constantly-changing environment. And many decades later, it often seems to me now that human society doesn't really "improve" over time. We get better technology, but all that means is we can kill each other more efficiently in never-ending wars.

@FumbleFingers Bleak … bleak outlook on the present and the future! Nevertheless, I can't help but give a certain credit to a belief in it and recognize a certain clear-sightedness in your assessment.

No, rules and logic should not be different for technical terms.  The term "cancellative semigroup" is not to be preferred, and this is so for the simple reason that a semigroup does not carry out an operation of cancellation, but that instead, it comprises certain features that make cancellation possible on both sides of the equalities that occur in the computations within the structure. The structure as a whole embodies this cancellation feature:  this is an internal feature.

(SOED) -ive Forming adjectives with the sense of 'tending to, having the nature of', as active, descriptive.

"Having the nature of cancelling" for a semigroup makes little sense. For instance, the effect that results from a descriptive paragraph is an external effect: nothing results from that quality as a particular modification within the  paragraph; similarly, a pensive man or an active man have an effect  upon something external to their person; a digestive tube carries out an action on what it contains, not in itself, that is, not on the walls of the intestine; a restrictive measure has an effect not within the measure itself but only on something else. There might be exceptions to this principle but I can't find one.
Only the  term "cancellation semigroup" seems therefore  proper.
In fact a definition is needed for both terms; the adjective is not sufficient, that is, compositionality does not tell you what type of semigroup you are dealing with.
(definition: A cancellation semigroup is a semigroup in which the law of cancellation is valid for the operation.)
Answer to user Peter's comment (Note though that mathematicians speak of commutative groups meaning groups with a commutative operation (one where a + b = b + a). The group and the operation that is part of its definition have the nature of commuting (in this sense).)
True, and there is not even the choice of "commutation group" for groups, but this is a case of two wrongs do not make a right.  The truth of the matter shows in the fact that the operation itself, which is a feature of the group structure, is also called "commutative", but what really commutes in these combinations through operating are the elements (a and b). A misnomer has never been called a preferable usage, it's just current usage that nobody could change for a term that does carry along the incriminated defects that the term "misnomer" implies.  "Commutation group" is also preferable, but, of course, it is not current usage. Nevertheless, nothing keeps a mathematician, on the occasion of a new publication, from introducing the new terminology "commutation group", even if the term is bound to find no echo in the mathematical community. This happens all the time and that is the reason for the existence of multiple terms for  entities that are one and the same thing. The terms "magma", "binar" and "groupoid" have been coined for the same structure; here there is much less a case for talking of preferable term since they are all more or less correct semantically. We are talking of preferences on the ground of linguistic legitimity, not on the ground of current usage, evidently. Usage has nothing to do in the question of considering the merit of a given term. Suppressing a discussion on the linguistic legitimacy of a term on the grounds that current usage does not license that term, is, in my opinion, not at all order.

Note though that mathematicians speak of commutative groups meaning groups with a commutative operation (one where a + b = b + a). The group and the operation that is part of its definition have the nature of commuting (in this sense).

@Peter: It mreans nothing to me, but Google Books has at least dozens of written instances of commutative semigroup. There may be one instance of commutation semigroup, but the specific publication doesn't support "preview", so even that one might not be "real".

@Peter I wrote my reply to your comment in my answer.

@PeterShor You propose new acceptations and -ive-ending terms, and they should be examined carefully, agreed, but in what concerns the present question, it seems to me that, "group belonging to commutativity" and "group serving to commutativity" are widely off the mark, without mentioning "group tending/serving to commutativity".  "Relates to commutativity" is much too vague: any group in which there is a proper commutative subset could be loosely said to relate to computativity; that does not have much meaning (expression of merely a vague connection).

There is no acceptation in English. The word is meaning. en ce qui concerne=in what concerns, which we do not use in English.  And I ain't reading the rest. By the way, are you sure that Peter here is PeterShor??

@Lambie The English language happens to be a language in which words can have synonyms (for your information), and "meaning" is just one of those , the meaning of "acceptation" in an elementary dictionary such as the OALD being "(linguistics) the meaning that a word or expression is generally accepted as having" (there is even "acception"); I am not altogether certain of the reason for your urge to throw that one overboard, I hardly believe that you should be unaware of it. // I suppose that the posters interested in English who have lingered on the present site for a couple (1/2)

@Lambie of years know very well that the Peter Shore posting on this site is the well known quantum computation engineer working at MIT; I am one of those posters. // By the way, the interesting comment (by Peter Shore) that prompted my reply to Peter Shore has been very probably removed by him in reason of the not entirely satisfactory argument it contained;  in spite of that it contained an apparently more encompassing definition than the SOED that deserved to be considered (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ive).  (2/2)

You mispell his name and think I don't know who he is?? His name=Peter Shor [no e!]. Here is his profile: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5754/peter-shor Geesus [of years know very well that etc.?] acception? NOPE. Not in the OALD. No exact match found for “acception” in English.  I tried to tell you nicely re Peter Shor... acceptation may be that in linguistics but it isn't common.

linguistic legitimity?? linguistic legitimacy. Among others.

@Lambie "Legitimity" is just another word for "legitimacy", except that it is rarely used; I shouldn't have to tell you such things: it is really your responsability to check them in  dictionaries.  I find this word in the SOED, and there is no  mention of a misspelling of "legitimacy'", as in some dictionaries online, which makes no sense; it's just rare.

No one says that in English. Rarely used unless you're a French speaker: légimité.

@Lambie You can't say "no one", really; here is an instance that is recent enough: "Labor Before the Industrial Revolution: Work, Technology and ... Thomas Max Safley · 2018". https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Labor_Before_the_Industrial_Revolution/oT33DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22legitimity%22&pg=PA105&printsec=frontcover. IPerhaps the French "légitimité" might have influenced my choice (3 occurrences in my posts and not a single one for "legitimacy"), although I know well this latter, usual term. Anyway, I do not feel the angst you seem to experience at the idea of rarely used words.

What gives me angst is the franglais. Your prose is often very heavy due to that. Sometimes, it's like walking knee deep in mud in flip-flops.

@Lambie Do not mistake! "Legitimity" IS English! There is no such word in French. It is an entry in the Oxford dictionary, or would you call the English of Thomas Max Safley "franglais"? By the way, "franglais" has not been quite anglicized yet: the entry is in italics in the SOED; I don't know whether you should indulge…

légitimité nom féminin [Yes, I misspelled it above!]

Caractère de ce qui est fondé en droit : La légitimité d'un contrat.
Synonyme : The franglais is yours, not his. If you like, I can copy your entire answer into chat and replace the franglais bits with better English.

